# Evaluate $\int_0^1\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^n\frac{1}{\ln x} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate: $$ I(n) = \int_0^1\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^n\frac{1}{\ln x} \,dx$$
> For $n \in \mathbb N$.

I started by noticing that $\int_0^1 x^y \,dy = (x-1)/\ln x$

So I can convert this into a double integral as follows:

$$I(n) = \int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{(x-1)^{n-1}x^y}{(x+1)^n}\,dy\,dx$$

Changing the order of integration and plugging in $x \rightarrow \cos 2\theta$, I get:

$$I(n) = 2(-1)^n\int_0^1 \int_0^{\pi/4}\tan^{2n-1}\theta \cos^y 2\theta \,d\theta \,dy$$

I have a feeling that I can somehow transform the inner integral into a Beta function, but the $\pi/4$ and $2\theta$ are a bit irritating and hard to get rid of.

Any methods to tackle this?

Comment: Maple does the case $n=1$ but not $n=2$.

Comment: $n = 1$ is simple enough, rewriting $1/(1+x)$ as $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-x)^k$ does it.

Comment: I think it should be $I(n) = 2(-1)^{n + \color{red}{1}}\int_0^1 ...$ at the end.

Comment: @VarunVejalla Sure, that should solve it.

Comment: For $n = 1$, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%28%28x-1%29%2F%28x%2B1%29%29%5E1*1%2Fln%28x%29+from+0+to+1) gives $\ln(\pi)-\ln(2)$. For $n = 2$, [it gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%28%28x-1%29%2F%28x%2B1%29%29%5E2*1%2Fln%28x%29+from+0+to+1) $-12\ln(A) + 1 - \frac{2\ln(2)}{3} + 2\ln(\pi)$, where $A$ is the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html)

Comment: I'd figured it out for $n=1$, But this result for $n=2$ doesn't look very promising for bigger values of $n$. It's difficult to believe that there can be a closed form for $I(n)$.

Comment: In general, it seems to be that $I(n) = n\ln(\pi) + a_n\ln(2) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} b_{n, k} \zeta'(-k)$, with the $a_n$ and $b_{n, k}$ rational numbers. $\zeta'(-1) = \frac{1}{12} -\ln(A)$, which is why the Glaisher-Kinkelin constant showed up.

Comment: @VarunVejalla this seems promising. I'd be happy if you can answer with a proof and provide some insight on what $a_n$ and $b_{n,k}$ could be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write $I_n$ for the integral and we introduce the following regularization:

$$ I_n(s) := - \int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^n (-\log x)^{s-1} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

This defines an analytic function for $\operatorname{Re}(s) > -n$. We aim at determining the expression of $I_n(s)$ using the principle of analytic continuation.

To this end, we temporarily assume that $s > n$. Then applying the substitution $x \mapsto e^{-x}$,

\begin{align*}
I_n(s)
&= - \int_{0}^{\infty}\left(2 - \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \right)^n x^{s-1}e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= - \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-2)^k \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^k} \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Now we utilize the following expansion

$$ \frac{z}{(1+z)^k} = \frac{1}{(k-1)!} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left[ {k-1 \atop j} \right] \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{l-1} l^j z^l, $$

valid for $k \geq 1$ and $|z| < 1$, where $\left[{n \atop k}\right]$ is the [unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind). Then for $k \geq 1$, using the fact that $s > n$, Fubini's Theorem yields

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^k} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= 
\frac{1}{(k-1)!} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left[ {k-1 \atop j} \right] \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{l-1} l^j \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}e^{-lx} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 
\frac{1}{(k-1)!} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left[ {k-1 \atop j} \right] \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{l-1} \frac{\Gamma(s)}{l^{s-j}} \\
&= 
\frac{1}{(k-1)!} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left[ {k-1 \atop j} \right] \Gamma(s)\eta(s-j),
\end{align*}

where

$$ \eta(s) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s} = (1 - 2^{1-s})\zeta(s) $$

is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function). Plugging this back, we get

\begin{align*}
I_n(s)
&= - \Gamma(s) \Biggl( 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-2)^k}{(k-1)!} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left[ {k-1 \atop j} \right] \eta(s-j) \Biggr).
\end{align*}

Although this equality is initially derived only for $s > n$, both sides define meromorphic functions on the region $\operatorname{Re}(s) > -n$, and as such, they must coincide on all of this region. Then, taking the limit as $s\to0$,

\begin{align*}
I_n = I_n(0)
&= - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-2)^k}{(k-1)!} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left[ {k-1 \atop j} \right] \eta'(-j) \\
&= - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-2)^k}{(k-1)!} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left[ {k-1 \atop j} \right] \left( 2^{1+j} \zeta(-j)\log 2 + (1-2^{1+j})\zeta'(-j) \right).
\end{align*}

The following table is generated by *Mathematica 11* using the above formula:

$$ \begin{array}{c|c}
\hline
n & I_n \\
\hline
 1 & \log (2 \pi )-2 \log (2) \\
 2 & -12 \log (A)+1-\frac{8 \log (2)}{3}+2 \log (2 \pi ) \\
 3 & -24 \log (A)-28 \zeta '(-2)+2-\frac{10 \log (2)}{3}+3 \log (2 \pi ) \\
 4 & -40 \log (A)+40 \zeta '(-3)-56 \zeta '(-2)+\frac{10}{3}-\frac{176 \log (2)}{45}+4 \log (2 \pi ) \\
 5 & -56 \log (A)-\frac{124}{3} \zeta '(-4)+80 \zeta '(-3)-\frac{308}{3} \zeta '(-2)+\frac{14}{3}-\frac{202 \log (2)}{45}+5 \log (2 \pi ) \\
\hline
\end{array} $$

Comment: Brilliant (as usual) !

Comment: Wow, there's so much I have to learn before I can even begin to comprehend this. Amazing work!

Comment: Sir, I asked the same question for n=1  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743811/evaluating-int-01-fracx-1x1-ln-x-dx) , can you continue from my method? and also the query regading the substitution $x \to \frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$I_n = \int_0^1\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^n\frac{1}{\log( x)} \,dx$$ For the first values of $n$,we have
$$I_1=-L_2+L_\pi$$
$$I_2=-12 L_A+1-\frac{2 L_2}{3}+2 L_\pi $$
$$I_3=-28 \zeta '(-2)-24 L_A+2-\frac{L_2}{3}+3 L_\pi$$
$$I_4=+40 \zeta '(-3)-56 \zeta '(-2)-40 L_A+\frac{10}{3}+\frac{4 L_2}{45}+4
   L_\pi$$
$$I_5=-\frac{124}{3} \zeta '(-4)+80 \zeta '(-3)-\frac{308}{3} \zeta
   '(-2)-56 L_A+\frac{14}{3}+\frac{23 L_2}{45}+5 L_\pi$$
$$I_6=\frac{168}{5} \zeta '(-5)-\frac{248}{3} \zeta '(-4)+160
   \zeta '(-3)-\frac{448}{3} \zeta '(-2)-\frac{372 L_A}{5}+\frac{31}{5}+\frac{926 L_2}{945}+6
   L_\pi$$ where $L_p=\log(p)$. Very few patterns seem to appear.

From a numerical point of view,  an empirical model such as
$$I_n=(-1)^n \frac{a+b\,n^c}{1+d\, n^e}$$ seems to be quite accurate. Built for $1 \leq n \leq 100$  $(R^2 > 0.9999999)$, the following parameters were obtained.
$$\begin{array}{llll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std.Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 2.674946 & 0.009256 & \{2.656568,2.693323\} \\
 b & 1.416719 & 0.001995 & \{1.412758,1.420680\} \\
 c & 0.827227 & 0.000893 & \{0.825453,0.829001\} \\
 d & 8.060723 & 0.023499 & \{8.014066,8.107380\} \\
 e & 1.984695 & 0.001326 & \{1.982062,1.987328\} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: @Integrand. Thanks for the edit ! It looks nicer. :-)